# Set system clock to local sidereal time (the time needed for astronomy)

Tags: indicator, time

Basically if you don't already know, the world is round, so we have timezones as an agreement. I want my system time to be set to LST.

I want to know what the local (determined from gps coords) time is on ubuntu, not the time in one of the timezones (for various sociopolitical reasons). Is there a package or script to set the system time based off of LST for current coordinates, rather than something more general, like a time zone?

Comment: found this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sunclock.1.html

Comment: This is called local sidereal time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you search is the  [LST (Local Solar Time)](http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/solar-time) or local sideral time, and you can use an [online page](http://fate.windada.com/cgi-bin/SolarTime_en) to see it.

[image]

As the OP found, there is the [sunclock application](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sunclock.1.html) which you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install sunclock
```

Run it (`sunclock` from the command line) and after you have resized the normally tiny window, you can switch from "map" mode to a "clock" mode by hitting `!` (you can have a very old-fashioned but IMHO nice menu by clicking in the window when in map-mode). In clock mode you click on the place you want and you'll have the local time.

Map-mode with the menu:
[image]

Clock mode: 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you seem to be looking for is called "Apparent solar time" and will not be part of the OS. You may be able to use a Search Engine to locate an application or algorithm that will help you calculate this based on GPS coordinate.

I did a quick check on Google and saw that the National Oceanic & Atmospheric Administration has a web page at http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/ that may help you with this.